# Java Maven Package Excel Files in Jar

Tags: java, excel, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have a few resource files (excel files) in my resource folder that I want to package into my jar so that when I assemble my project it'll package the excel files into the jar and the user won't have to provide additional files when running the jar.

My project structure is like this:

```
/MyApp
   |-src
   |---main
   |-----java
   |-------app
   |---------Main.java
   |-----resources
   |-------Something.xlsx
```

Here's my maven pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <!-- regular resource processsing for everything except logback.xml -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here's how I assemble my jar:

```
clean compile assembly:single
```

This creates my jar but when I run the jar like `java -jar myjar.jar` I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/me/IdeaProjects/MyApp/target/myjar.jar!/Something.xlsx (No such file or directory)
```

Clearly the excel file is not getting packaged into the jar. Here's the java code that attempts to open the resource file:

```
URL file = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Something.xlsx");
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want? If so/not, what's the best approach in this situation?

Comment: @Rechard Why don't you place resource dir inside src directory?

Comment: Have you tried opening your jar with something like `WinZip` to ensure the excel files were actually packaged in the jar?

Comment: @gonzo it looks like the excels are inside the jar but for some reason still can't find it.

Comment: @Richard That is good news!  That means the POM is correct. You might want to just play around with the java code that opens the resource file in question. Try `"resources/Something.xlsx"`..

Comment: or just `/Something.xlsx`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to use a InputStream instead of an URL. So now my code reads like this:

```
InputStream file = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Something.xlsx");
```

This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I am having similar issues. I have excel test data file under "data" folder that is created for the root.

2020-04-02 16:00:44 DEBUG Log:46 - Reading SMAPI UI Automation Excel data file

Excel file path    : data/SMAPI_UI_Automation.xlsx

Excel Reading have problems :  java.lang.NullPointerException

code is : **ExcelUtils.java**

```
  try {
        String vXlsxFilePath = "data/" + fileName;

        System.out.println("Excel file path"+vXlsxFilePath);

        InputStream ExcelFile = ExcelUtils.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(vXlsxFilePath);

        //FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(vXlsxFilePath);   
        ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Excel Reading have problems"+e);
        Log.error("Excel Reading have problems"+e);
    }
```